# Synchronize MySQL ID's with JTable rows

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I've a program that uses inf from a MySQL table to create rows in a `JTable`. I use an auto incrementing `ID` but whenever I delete a row from the database (and therefor the `JTable`) and then add a new one, I have a gab in between the `ID`'s.

For example right now my MySQL table stores 3 rows with `ID` 1,2 and 4 which are stored in the `JTable` as rows with rownumber 1,2 and 3. This really messes up my logics.

Therefor I want to know if there is a way to make it so that whenever I delete a row from that table, all rows below there will have their ID updated so there are no gaps between `ID`'s.

I was hoping this could be achieved with a query, can it?

Comment: `I was hoping this could be achieved with a query, can it?` - isn't the auto incrementing ID part of the table? Can't you just return that ID from the SQL query and then display that value in the JTable? The point of having a key to a table is that it doesn't change over time. So resetting the ID when you delete a row doesn't make sense.

Comment: no because I use the table model which automatically gives the row that ID for example when using a custom renderer the rows are counted like that.

Comment: That was my point. Don't automatically sequence the rows. The ID number should NOT change. Use the ID from the SQL table to display in the JTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even tho the question doesn't make that much sense, you can execute a query every time you delete an row. the only thing you have to know is which id you deleted. then you execute this:

```
set @a=id-1
go
update tablename set id=@a:=@a+1
```

`id-1` means that if you delete id 5 you set it to 4 so your row 6,7,8.. are now 5,6,7...

Answer (score 0):

you can add a column of mysqlID in your tablemodel like this

```
String [] columnNames = {"Sno ","mysql ID","Name" };
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames ,0);
```

run query and populate column "mysql ID" with id in your DB 
and if you want to hide this column you can remove it from table, type this code in constructor

`tableName.removeColumn(tableName.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));`

if you want id of a particular row in jtable you can get it from its(tabel) model

`mysqlLID = (int)dtm.getValueAt(tableName.getSelectedRow(), 1);`